# why does ckeditor contentcss not load

Tags: ckeditor

Was working on server log reports:

```
[20/Mar/2016 22:52:22] "GET /tm/edit_blocks HTTP/1.1" 200 1932
```

Now this line does not appear

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CKEditor</title>
        <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="editor0" name="editor0"><p>Editor</p>{{ block0.html }}</textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace('editor0'), {contentsCss : '/static/tm/style2.css'};
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load an extra plugin

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor0'), {extraPlugins : 'stylesheetparser',contentsCss : '/static/tm/style2.css'};
```

**edit**
the original code should be updated:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor0',{contentsCss :'/static/tm/style3.css'});
```

Comment: I'm not using stylesheetparser. I am setting the editor's config.contentsCss. According to the documentation there are 2 ways to set config options:`CKEDITOR.replace('editor0'), {contentsCss : '/static/tm/style3.css'};
    CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/static/tm/style3.css'`
I started out using the first, and it worked, Now neither work,

Comment: I have always had problems with contentscss not working without the parser. Can you try this?

**CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor0',{contentsCss :'/static/tm/style3.css'});**

Comment: Thank you. I had a blind spot - ")" in the wrong place. Now it works.

Comment: If that fixed the problem, I updated my answer that you can accept  as the answer :)